# Consulta laravel no funciona correctamente

Tags: php, laravel

Hola a todos necesito su ayuda ya que llevo un buen rato buscando y no encuentro el error, soy nuevo en laravel 8 y tengo en mi base de datos una tabla con un `id` y un `title` que es el título de la categoría, y en laravel tengo mi modelo que representa esa tabla y lo tengo de esta forma:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'category';
}
```

Como la tabla solo tiene los campos anteriormente mencionados no apunta a ningun lado la tabla, por lo que la deje asi, ahora desde un controlador quiero seleccionar todos los datos de esa tabla y tengo el codigo de esta forma usando el `namespace` de mi modelo:

```
$categories = Category::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

return view('books.create', ['categories' => $categories]);
```

El problema es que cuando quiero mostrar el título(`title`) desde la vista me dice que da este error:

```
Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /var/www/html/proyecto-laravel/resources/views/books/create.blade.php)
```

La forma en la que lo muestro es solo para revisar que los datos me llegaran y lo hago asi:

```
<?php var_dump($categories->title); die(); ?>
```

Quiero volver a decir que soy nuevo y no se mucho de laravel 8 en específico, desde ya gracias :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La consulta no es incorrecta, sin embargo la forma en que pretendes acceder a la información que estaría devolviendo si.

Explico:

- Actualmente tu query retorna una colección de objetos.

  - Posible salida 1. Si encuentra datos se verá de esta forma la estructura:

    ```
    [
        {},
        .....................
    ]
    ```
  - Posible salida 2. Si no encuentra datos, aún así la salida será un array vacío

    ```
     []
    ```

Entonces tomando como referencia el primer caso, para que tu código funcionara y muestre el título debería ser de esta forma:

```
$categories[indice]->title
```

Donde lo que se hace es, indicar entre corchetes la el índice donde esta el objeto y posterior la propiedad de la cual se requiere acceder a su valor.

Sin embargo, la aproximación anterior tiene sus limitantes como lo es el hecho de que si tu query retorna 2 o mas objetos entonces tendrás que repetir dicha línea de código N cantidad de veces cambiando el valor del índice para mostrar todos los registros de títulos.

Luego entonces puedes iterar dicha colección para acceder e imprimir de forma dinámica cada valor.

Para lo anterior, recomiendo leas este apartado de la [documentación.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops)

Comment: Gracias @BetaM, de la forma en la que sugeriste ya funciono, después ya solo añadí un pequeño bucle y estuvo listo